# Unusual vortex actions along vehicle roof

Tags: flow, aerodynamics, vortex

Let me open by stating that I do understand the ethical implications of my failure to brush the snow off my roof.

After arriving at work I noticed an unusual snow erosion pattern on the roof of my car. Normally it clearly illustrates the attached airflow and it's eventual detachment. This time, it displayed a more unusual pattern indicative of multiple multiple vortices parallel to the roofline. The car is an unmodified Chevy Sonic and travel speed was between 30 and 50 mph. The snow was fairly powdery.

My friend and I are trying to track this down out of curiosity l. The pictures were taken shortly after arrival.

[image: rear of vehicle]

[image: front detail]

[image: front wide]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the cause.

while driving your car, the air in front of it is pushed up and over the roof, causing that air to speed up. this produces a low-pressure zone above the car's roof.  air adjacent to the sides of the car gets pulled up towards the roof and swirls around to mix with the air flowing over the roof. sitting inside the car, the swirl is clockwise on the driver's side and counterclockwise on the passenger side.

Each swirl can be modeled as a tornado tipped over on its side, with its tip at the point where the upper left and upper right-hand corner of the windshield meet the roof. These swirls are called vortices and they meet in the center of the roof, flow downwards, split, and spin around. In doing so they scour away all the loose powder on the roof in that central zone where the opposing vortices collide.

Comment: like a torn... what? A tornado is a very complicated entity (involving suction vortices and similar) caused by a convective storm, usually a mesocyclone? How do you want model a normal vortex in turbulent flow like a tornado? I also do not buy the rest either. The flow is probably modified by the antena. The swirls (somewhat analogical to wing tip vortices) may be responsible of the snow missing at the sides of the pile, not in the centre.

Comment: Is it really possible for something to modify the air stream that far ahead? I didn't think it was possible at this low of a speed

Comment: it actually is. -NN